# Unix: Cut a string along with delimiter

Tags: shell, unix

I am using below command to cut a string based on delimiter. But i want the output to be printed along with delimiter.

**Sample string:** test_file.txt

**Command:**

```
echo "test_file.txt" | cut -sd_ -f1
```

Current output: test

Expected output: test_

EDIT: i am using cut -sd to report null if the string doesnt contain the delimiter. so if the delimiter is not present, i should get output as null too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using BASH then there is no external tool required:

```
s='test_file.txt'
[[ $s == *_* ]] && echo "${s%%_*}"_

test_
```

Or using `sed`:

```
sed -n 's/_.*/_/p' <<< "$s"

test_
```

Or using `awk`:

```
awk -F_ 'NF>1{print $1 FS}' <<< "$s"

test_
```

Comment: Thank you for quick solution.. I am using sd in cut command, so that it reports null if there is no delimiter present. Does that can be done through above commands too? For e.g. if i use testfile.txt, i should get output as null as the delimiter is not present

Comment: Yes, all the options in my edited answer will take care of that.

Comment: Thank you so much :) Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with `cut`, but you can do it with `sed`:

```
$ echo "test_file.txt" | sed 's/\([^_]*_\).*$/\1/'
test_
```

If you want nothing at all to be printed if there is no `_`, the simplest approach is probably to weed out those lines separately,

```
$ echo "test_file.txt" | sed '/^[^_]*$/d; s/\([^_]*_\).*$/\1/'
```

Comment: Thank you for quick solution.. I am using sd in cut command, so that it reports null if there is no delimiter present. Does that can be done through sed too? For e.g. if i use testfile.txt, i should get output as null as the delimiter is not present.

Comment: My original command would leave lines containing no `_` unchanged; I have added another option that behaves as you ask.

Answer (score 0):

```
 echo "test_file.txt"  |grep -oP '^.*?_'
 test_
```

This will print anything from start of the line till the *first* delimiter ( `_` ) including delimiter.